# What's the meaning of "finniky"?

Tags: meaning, orthography, variants

There is this sentence in a letter of Bertrand Russell:

> Even the absurdities - the thunder and lightning - are big and invigorating after the stifling *finniky* appropriateness of everything French.

I couldn't find this anywhere. Is it a typo? The following words have similar spelling : *finicky*, *Finnic*, *finicking* (also *finikin*, *finnicking*, *finnikin*).

Comment: Well, if one were being finniky one might object to spelling "French" with all lower-case.

Comment: If one was Bertrand Russell, one could spell things any way one wished. ;-)

Comment: If you read the definitions of the similar words you found, it should be clear that *[finicky](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/finicky)* was almost certainly the intended word.

Comment: See also: persnickety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the seventeenth and eighteenth centuries—and indeed until World War I, the dominant form of the word that we now know as *finicky* was *finical*. Here is an Ngram chart of the variants *finical* (yellow line) versus *finicky* (red line) versus *finnicky* (blue line) versus *finiky* (green line) versus *finniky* (no line) for the years 1785–2005:

[image]

The reason the spelling *finniky* has no line in this chart is that Google reports "Ngrams not found" for that spelling—an announcement that it makes when the Google Books matches for a particular spelling fall below some threshold number. Nevertheless, a Google Books search for *finniky* turns up close to 80 matches, going back to the first half of the nineteenth century.

One interesting early instance is this one from John Brockett, [*A Glossary of North Country Words, in Use*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Rxm7CtWO7D4C&pg=PA83&dq=%22gliff+a+slight%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iYUXVJTHJoHDigL_m4CwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22finniking%2C%20finniky%22&f=false) (1825):

> FINNIKING, **FINNIKY,** trifling, scrupulously particular. Perhaps variations of *finical*.

The third edition of Brockett, [*A Glossary of North Country Words, with Their Ethymology, and Affinity to Other Languages*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ev1IAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA167&dq=%22finniky%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvwoXV0I_LAhUJ9GMKHeY4A2I4FBDoAQhEMAg#v=onepage&q=%22finniky%22&f=false) (1846) dispenses with *finniking* but sticks with *finniky* and loses any doubt about the connection to *finical*:

> **FINNIKY,** trifling, scrupulously particular—*finical*.

Another dictionary notice occurs in James Donald, [*Chambers's English Dictionary: Pronouncing, Explanatory, and Etymological*](https://books.google.com/books?id=UqMRAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA926&dq=%22finniky%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzipDG0I_LAhUS3GMKHUSeDIA4ChDoAQg2MAU#v=onepage&q=%22finniky%22&f=false) (1872), which curiously enough lists it in what amounts to an appendix of "Americanisms":

> *Finnikin*, *Finniking*, ***Finniky***, finical.

The spelling *finniky* continues to appear sporadically in English publications until at least 1928, after which the possibility that occurrences are simply typos becomes more likely, as the spelling *finicky* becomes more and more dominant.

Russell's use of *finniky* occurs in a letter to Alys Pearsall Smith dated "1–2 October 1894 midnight" and is reprinted in [*The Selected Letters of Bertrand Russell: The Private Years, 1884–1914*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-SnXAAAAMAAJ&q=%22finniky%22&dq=%22finniky%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii-Lfw6I_LAhUMwWMKHa0TDow4MhDoAQg8MAg) (1992). The years 1884–1914 are roughly the period when *finicky* went from a very low frequency of occurrence to a frequency almost equal to that of *finical*, and 1894 is well within the era when *finniky* still occasionally appeared in print as an acceptable variant form.

Comment: That's amazing explanation as always. But I wonder why OED has no record of this. It reports on all of the other variations except for _finniky_.

Comment: @alex - Even OED probably draws the line at variants that amount to 0.001% of the total.  But the larger point is that "official" English spelling has not been "official" (in the sense that OED is) for more than perhaps 80-100 years.  The OED has only been published in bound volumes since 1928, and back then they didn't have computers to keep track of all the words.